# Filedownload by dojo script

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

I am trying to download a file by referring to below link and code.
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/ajax/Content/sforce_api_ajax_queryresultiterator.htm#base64issue
But for some reason text area appears as blank..any idea where i am going wrong

```
<apex:page showHeader="false">
<apex:includeScript value="/soap/ajax/29.0/connection.js"/>
<apex:includeScript value="/resource/dojo.js"/>
<script> 
function setup() {
sforce.connection.sessionId = “{!$Api.Session_ID}” 

  var document_ta = document.getElementById("document-ta");

  sforce.connection.query("select name, id from document where id = 015i0000000lEAg",
    {onSuccess : querySuccess,
     onFailure : function(error, doc_ta) {
        doc_ta.value = "Oops something went wrong: " + error;
     },
     source: document_ta});
}

function querySuccess(result, doc_ta) {
sforce.connection.sessionId = “{!$Api.Session_ID}” 
  var records = result.getArray("records");

//if (records.length == 1) {
    dojo.io.bind({
      url: "/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=" + records[0].Id,
      load: loadDocument});
 // } else {
   // doc_ta.value = "no records found";
  //}
}

function loadDocument(type, data, event) {
sforce.connection.sessionId = “{!$Api.Session_ID}” 
  var document_ta = document.getElementById("document-ta");
  document_ta.value = data;
}

</script>

<apex:form >
<body onload="setup()">
<textarea id="document-ta" cols="80" rows="20">
</textarea>
</body>
</apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

Comment: just realising that this code has some cross domain issues.although its from sfdc

Answer (score 1):

Did you ever get this to work? I had fits with it. Ultimately found that loadDocument was not running with the code copied from that ajax documentation we were both referencing. Verified with alerts or console.logs at various points.

One change that did result in writing to the textarea was changing the URL passed to dojo.io.bind. For instance, if I added a '.' for the current directory (making it url: "**.**/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=" + records[0].Id), it would dump data to the textarea - but that data was a VisualForce error page. This change caused it to (finally) call the loadDocument function but had made the path include the apex directory, so SF treated it like a request for an Apex page. The request was obviously invalid, though.

The point is, if I made the url invalid, it would call loadDocument and write the resulting error page to the textarea; with an apparently valid path, though, it wouldn't call loadDocument at all.

I never resolved the dojo.io.bind/loadDocument issue but was able to work around it. I replaced the call to dojo.io.bind with a call to window.open. It's not the way I'd prefer to do it and I'll revisit it at some point. The textarea and the call to loadDocument are no longer needed. Here's my onSuccess function (renamed to downloadFiles rather than querySuccess):

```
function downloadFiles(result, source) {
  var files = result.getArray("records");
  if (files.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0;i<files.length;i++) {
      window.open("/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=" + files[i].Id);
    }
  } else {
    alert("no records found");
  }
}
```

One other thing to note: initially I also got invalid session errors with the original path to connection.js. In that environment I changed the path to use 30.0 rather than 29.0 and it worked. However, when I tested in another environment, 30.0 didn't work for one of the testers but worked for the other (and for me). I changed back to 29.0 in that environment and it worked for all. Strange.

Comment: Even I am struggling with the same issue. loadDocument is never invoked.